# Twig 2.0 Year Array

Tags: php, html, twig

I have a Set and For statement using Twig 2.0 and I'm having issues getting it to generate a year array from 2020-2070. It generates 50 options but the options are from 0-50 instead of 2020-2070. Here's my code:

```
{% set start_year = "now"|date('Y') %}
{% set end_year = start_year + 50 %}
{% for year in start_year..end_year %}
<option value="{{ loop.index0}}">{{ loop.index0 }}</option>
```

Comment: Have you checked what your start year is coming back as? If the start_year is 0 then you'll probably find that's the cause of your problem. Please add some more debugging details though as to what you've tried so far.

Comment: If you want to display the year, use the variable `year` and not `loop.index0`?

Comment: I've tried set start_year = 2020, same issue, I tried replacing loop with year and then nothing shows up in the options just 50 dropdown slots. I've tried date()|date("Y") and same issue with showing 0-50 in the dropdown list instead of the years.

Comment: I echoed out the start year with this twig code: {{ 'now'  | date('Y') }} and it came back as 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to display the `year` variable, indeed and not the `loop.index0` that is:

> The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)

<sup>*Source: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable*</sup>

So:

```html
{% for year in "now"|date('Y').."now"|date('Y')+50 -%}
  <option value="{{ year }}">{{ year }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Render:

```html
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<!-- cut for brevity -->
<option value="2069">2069</option>
<option value="2070">2070</option>
```

<sub>*Fiddle: https://twigfiddle.com/ee0fiz*</sub>

Comment: My next question would be how can I set the variable "Time" within the Twig 2.0 Set Tag using a form to select a Month and Year, and how can I get the events to show up under the correct date in my calendar?

Comment: Here's a link to my View File event.html: https://pastebin.com/Vwhnv6Gq and here is a link to my live website event page: http://jointspecialoperationsgroup.com/event/index